# Function which returns a QList

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qsharedpointer

I have the following classes

```
class LMJEntity : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int Id READ getId WRITE setId)
};

class LMJDataMapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    virtual QList<LMJEntity *> *findAll(LMJPaging *paging){
        QList<LMJEntity *> * result = NULL;
        QSqlQuery query;    
        bool ret;       
        ret = query.exec(sql);

        if(!ret){
            errors = query.lastError().text();      
        }else
        {
           result = new QList<LMJEntity *>();
           while(query.next()){
                result->append(load(query));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

Is this a correct way to use `QList`? Should I use `QSharedPointer` instead of raw pointer to avoid memory leak?
Please give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point using `QSharedPointer` inside the `QList` if the `QList` instance itself is a normal pointer. Once you loose the pointer to `QList`, you loose all the memory allocated by shared pointers inside the list.

It is not necessary to pass `QList` and all the Qt container-classes including `QString` by pointers. They use shared-pointers internally, so passing a `QList` is from the performance perspective more or less the same as passing `QList*` (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html).

Whether using QSharedPointers for wrapping `LMJEntity` is a matter of concrete usage. In any case, it won't harm.
Your `LMJEntity` class is derived from `QObject`. QObjects are deleted automatically with their parents. So if you provide a parent to your `LMJEntity` instances, than they needn't be shared pointers.

If not, they will be children of the application, and never be deleted. More than that, they will never be detected as memory leaks by any memleak-checking software.

Answer (score 0):

QList is small enough, so normally you do not need to allocate memory for it in the heap. I would write something like this:

```
class LMJEntity : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int Id READ getId WRITE setId)
};
typedef QSharedPointer < LMJEntity > PLMJEntity;

class LMJDataMapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    virtual const QList < PLMJEntity > findAll(LMJPaging *paging) {
        QList < PLMJEntity > result;
        QSqlQuery query;    
        if (!query.exec(sql)) {
            errors = query.lastError().text();      
        } else {
            while (query.next()) {
                result->append(PLMJEntity(load(query)));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```